# Split owner and object name in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Given an object identified by the form `owner.tablename`; how do I split the owner and table name up?

Both my ideas of either string tokenization or `select owner, object_name from all_objects where owner || '.' || object_name = 'SCHEMA.TABLENAME'` seem like hacks.

Comment: Why hacks? You cannot have "." in an identifier (i.e. inside owner or inside object_name).

Comment: @kubanczyk Actually you can if you enclose the object name in double quotes: `CREATE TABLE "test . table ) @" (id NUMBER);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_UTILITY.name_tokenize` for this purpose.

> This procedure calls the parser to parse the given name as "a [. b [.
>   c ]][@ dblink ]". It strips double quotes, or converts to uppercase if
>   there are no quotes. It ignores comments of all sorts, and does no
>   semantic analysis. Missing values are left as NULL.

e.g.

```
DBMS_UTILITY.NAME_TOKENIZE
 ( name    => 'SCHEMA.TABLENAME'
 , a       => v_schema
 , b       => v_object_name
 , c       => v_subobject -- ignore
 , dblink  => v_dblink
 , nextpos => v_nextpos -- ignore
 );
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#BJEFIFBJ

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('SCHEMA.TABLENAME', 0, INSTR('SCHEMA.TABLENAME', '.') - 1) OWNER,
      SUBSTR('SCHEMA.TABLENAME', INSTR('SCHEMA.TABLENAME', '.') + 1) TABLE_NAME
FROM DUAL
```